# Starting an alternate activity on startup if certain conditions satisfy

Tags: android, android-activity, oncreate

- I am creating an app that requires some settings to be set first
  before starting the display activity.
             I would like the app to check if a preference file (that contains these settings) exists and if it does exist move to a
  particular activity or remain in the main activity(as the settings
  activity is my main activity).
- I tried to use startactivty() on startup, but it shows the settings
  menu for a fraction of a second before moving on to the display
  activity.
- how should I do it?

  I tried the following code:

  ```
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);          
          SharedPreferences prefsfile = getSharedPreferences("myfile",0); 

          if( prefsfile!=null & Timetablledisplay.flag==0){
              Intent i=new Intent(ProjectBunkitActivity.this,Timetablledisplay.class);
              startActivity(i);
          }
  ```

Comment: Post your code. what have you tried earlier?

Comment: Have you tried adding the `finish()` tag after you call `startActivity(i)` to close your current activity?

Comment: the code is working well but I need the Timetabledisplay activity to start without showing the settings activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option for a potential workaround for this problem would be taking a slightly different approach:

Instead of launching into Settings, and then deciding whether or not to go to the Timetablleddisplay activity, you could start in a blank activity that simply decides which activity to launch.

The activity could be something like this:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);      
    SharedPreferences prefsfile = getSharedPreferences("myfile",0); 

    if( prefsfile!=null && Timetablledisplay.flag==0){
        Intent i=new Intent(CURRENT.this,Timetablledisplay.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
    else
    {
        Intent i=new Intent(CURRENT.this,ProjectBunkitActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: @iKiar, why do you need to call `setContentView` here?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I just copied the OPs code from above and forgot to remove it.

Comment: I'm glad. Don't forget to accept the answers that work for you!

Answer (score 2):

You should have the `LAUNCHER` `Activity` call `startActivity()` on the new `Activity` (*plus* `finish()`) in `onCreate()` before calling `setContentView()` when needed. This way, the new `Activity` will be launched "behind the scenes" before an attempt at inflating any layout is made.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myFile", 0); 

    if(prefs != null && ActivityOne.flag == 0) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityOne.class);
        startActivity(i);
    } else {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    finish();
}
```